# VBA Excel - Looping through a large data set and finding average of certain rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to writing in VBA and am struggling with the following task.

I have a workbook with multiple sheets with a large set of data in each (10000 rows). I am able to remove the data I don't need quite easily and can sort the data. I am left with column 1 - a list of Parts, and columns 4 and 5 - Planned Time and Actual Time.

What I want to do with this data is to find the average of columns 4 and 5 for each unique value in column 1. I thought it would be easiest to do the following

1. Loop for each worksheet
2. Sort the data for "Part"
3. Create a variable array
4. Loop for each row
5. If the previous row "Part" is the same as the current row then add the that row's "Planned Time" and "Actual Time" to the variable array
6. If the previous row "Part" is different calculate the average of data in the variable array
7. Output the averages to a Results sheet with their unique "Part"

Any help would be appreciated. Mainly how to work with the variable array and how to perform the check to fill the array. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't a Pivot table do just that?

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

I've put this VBA macro togther for you which should do the trick. The script will loop through all your worksheets and summarise the info into an array (ask you asked). The array is then output into the results table.

*Note : You will need to ensure that your workbook contains a sheet called "Results". The script will output the details you need to the "Results" sheet.*

```
Option Explicit


Sub getResults()

'set variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim partName As String

'set array to contain the parts/avarage data
Dim partsAverageArray() As Variant
ReDim partsAverageArray(1 To 4, 1 To 1)


'loop through each sheet in the workbook
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    'ignore worksheet if it's name is "Results"
    If Not ws.Name = "Results" Then

        'get last row in the sheet using column A (size of the table of parts)
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'loop down the table of parts data starting at row 2 (assuming that row 1 contains the heading of the columns
        i = 2
        For i = 2 To lastRow

            'get the part name
            partName = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

            'check if the part does/does not exist within the array yet
            'loop through the array to get this info

            'check if array has any info in it yet
            If partsAverageArray(1, 1) = "" Then
                'array is blank so add the first part
                'add part name
                partsAverageArray(1, 1) = partName
                'part occurences
                partsAverageArray(2, 1) = 1
                'sum of time planned
                partsAverageArray(3, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                'sum of time taken (actual)
                partsAverageArray(4, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value

            Else
                'array already exists so loop through it looking for a part match
                ii = 1
                 For ii = 1 To UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)
                    'test for a part match
                     If partsAverageArray(1, ii) = partName Then
                        'match found
                        'so add/cumulate data into the array
                        'part occurences (add 1)
                        partsAverageArray(2, ii) = partsAverageArray(2, ii) + 1
                        'sum of time planned (total)
                        partsAverageArray(3, ii) = partsAverageArray(3, ii) + ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                        'sum of time taken (actual) (total)
                        partsAverageArray(4, ii) = partsAverageArray(4, ii) + ws.Cells(i, 5).Value

                        'stop the loop of the array
                        ii = UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)

                     Else
                        'part name does not match
                        'check if the end of the array has been reached
                        If ii = UBound(partsAverageArray, 2) Then
                            'the end of the array has been reached and the part not found
                            'therefore add an additional dimension to the array and put the part's details into it
                            ReDim Preserve partsAverageArray(1 To 4, 1 To (UBound(partsAverageArray, 2) + 1))
                            'add part name
                            partsAverageArray(1, UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)) = partName
                            'part occurences
                            partsAverageArray(2, UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)) = 1
                            'sum of time planned
                            partsAverageArray(3, UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                            'sum of time taken (actual)
                            partsAverageArray(4, UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value

                            'stop the loop of the array
                            ii = UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)

                        Else
                            'part name has not been found and the array has not looped to the end.
                            'therefore keep the array looping and do nothing

                        End If

                     End If

                 Next ii

            End If

        Next i

    End If

Next ws




'--------------------------------------------------------
'output data from the array to the reults sheet
'--------------------------------------------------------

Set ws = Sheets("Results")
'set the results table headings
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Part"
ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Part Count"
ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Planned Time (Average)"
ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Actual Time (Average)"

'clear the old results from the table before adding the new results
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A2:D" & lastRow).ClearContents


i = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(partsAverageArray, 2)
    'part name
    ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = partsAverageArray(1, i)
    'part count
    ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = partsAverageArray(2, i)
    'average (planned)
    ws.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = partsAverageArray(3, i) / partsAverageArray(2, i)
    'average (actual)
    ws.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = partsAverageArray(4, i) / partsAverageArray(2, i)
Next i

'view results
ws.Activate


End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem @MarkCooper . Pleased to be able to help!